# AngularJS clone element and animate position

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm new to AngularJS, and I want to make simple animation like PrestaShop shows when user click "Add to cart" button on the product.

I found nice article about animations in AngularJS, but there is a few methods of doing that...

Suppose I have a grid list of products with photos for each of them and button with text "Add to cart". When user click on it the photo should be "cloned", opacity should be 0.5 and this photo should slide position to cart which is on the top of the site.

I have one concept:

Photos in ng-repeat can be rendered twice, where one of them is like hidden "behind the second" and the mentioned "clone" with animate should take affect of them, but how to make it in AngularJS manner? (if this is good idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support old browsers, instead of rendering the photo twice, try something like this;

Set a CSS to change the opacity, say:

```
.opaque {
    opacity: 0.5;
    /* and maybe other browser specific opacity settings */
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<img src="...." ng-class="{opaque:isOpaque}" />
<button type="button" ng-click="isOpaque=true">Add to cart</button>
```

As you can see, the ng-class on the `<img>` is set to 'opaque', which will only be activated if `isOpaque === true`. The 'Add to cart' button will then set isOpaque to true when clicked.

The rest is just to prepare your controller as usual.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply, but what about the animation of the position for "cloned" photo?